# Google Photos Video Streaming not Working in Safari

Tags: html5-video, google-photos, google-photos-api

I'm trying to get a playable video from a url of a video stored on Google Photos. The documentation suggests adding "=dv" to the base_url

It play video in Chrome, Firefox but not in Safari.

How do I go about playing video in Safari from Google Photos API?

If I add "=m18" instead of "=dv" it will play a compressed version of video in Safari. But Google recommend to not use "=m18"

`<div class="videoHolder" style="position: absolute; width: 1200px; height: 675px; top: 180.5px; left: 251px;">
    <video id="video" width="1200" height="675" autoplay="" controls="true" preload="" playsinline="" muted="" poster="342278662.mp4"><source src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/lr/really_long_url=dv" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>`

I'm expecting the video to stream, but I just see the buffering symbol

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Google Photos Library API does not currently support video streaming. If you want to access a video for playback, you have to use the `=dv` [base URL parameter](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/access-media-items#video-base-urls) to download the file first.

Unfortunately this is a known limitation, you can follow the feature request on the issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/111931138
If you have a specific use case in mind or technology that should be supported, please add details to the feature request.